# When an ObservedObject passed into a view is updated, the SwiftUI doesn't update?

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, observedobject

I have a view called SearchResults. It should update whenever the ObservedObject passed into it changes, but the View is not updating with the new values and I'm not sure why.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchResults: View {
    @ObservedObject var VModel: ViewModel
    var body: some view {
        List {
            ForEach(self.VModel.searchResults, id: \.self) { result in 
                Text(result)
            }
        }
    }
}


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var searchResults: [String] = []

    func findResults() {
        //Do the update to 'searchResults' here
        //This function is called at another point in the code in a pretty big file...I think it might make it more confusing to have like a couple hundred more lines of code in here
    }
}
```

Side Note: VModel has an array of type [String] called searchResults, and I thought this view should update whenever the searchResults array is updated..?

Comment: Does the property `searchResults` have `@Published` property wrapper?

Comment: @NewDev Yes it does

Comment: Can you show a full code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @OOPer I updated it a little bit, I'm not sure if you want the whole code or not, because it's hundreds of lines

Comment: @nickcoding - i don't see anything in this code to indicate a problem. Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, but I want to see a code enough to reproduce your issue. With filling up your `findResults()` and some other parts with the right code to run your code shown, nothing like you have described happens and the View is updated correctly. You have something wrong where you have not shown yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all the confusion everyone, evidently I'm really stupid. I was creating a new ViewModel() instance instead of passing in the one declared in ContentView